# HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized Asana API

Tags: asana

PROBLEM: I cannot authorize my connection to ASANA.

Breaking my code to the simplist bits. I used: http://onlinecurl.com/ to mimic what I see at

```
https://asana.com/developers/documentation/getting-started/authentication#sts=API%20Keys
```

This is my command.

```
curl --user 'NWE2MDJqUloubnpCUjh0d3gxVmYydW5BeFlJUER0Smw6' https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/users/me
```

Original : 5a602jRZ.nzBR8twx1Vf2unAxYIPDtJl

I even used https://www.base64encode.org/ to make sure my base64 was correct, which it is.

Response Header

```
1 HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
2 Server: nginx
3 Date: Sat, 25 Oct 2014 17:58:23 GMT
4 Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
5 Transfer-Encoding: chunked
6 Connection: keep-alive
7 X-Asana-Content-String-Length: 41
8 Pragma: no-cache
9 Set-Cookie: TooBusyRedirectCount=0
10 Cache-Control: no-store
11 X-Asana-Preferred-Release-Revision: 20141024_201328_7ebcb21240775f3d5e6038b42ade419530485b76
12 X-Robots-Tag: none
```

Response Body

```
1{"errors":[{"message":"Not Authorized"}]}
```

How can I connect to the service with my Authorization???

Since writing this I have reset my aPIKEY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There needs to be a content Header 
Here is what I did in Google Scripts.

In the site : http://onlinecurl.com/ 
we would need an extra option in headers for content-type

```
function getTasksFromAsana() {
  api_key = "XXXX";
  workspace_id = "WORKSPACE-ID";

  // set up HTTPS connection
  uri = "https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/users/me";

  // set up the request
  req={};
  req = {
    "headers":{ 'content-type': 'application/json','authorization': 'Basic ' + api_key }
  }



  Logger.log('Get Tasks Asana');

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(uri,req);

  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to base64-encode the username yourself, curl will do that for you. Also, please be careful of sharing your API key on public forums; these are sensitive credentials that should be treated like usernames and passwords! If that is a real API key I advise you reset it immediately (which you can do through the UI where you discovered it).

Comment: thanks I reset it already. I reset it as soon as I ... before I even posted this link. I didn't want any one to answer this post saying ,"it's becuase your key is 'XXXXXX'"